# Django Truncate, return false if no truncation occurs?

Tags: django

In my template I am trying to check if a sentence is truncated. I have written a def in my model:

```
def read_more_needed(self):
        from django.utils.text import Truncator
        return Truncator(self.description).words(5, html=True, truncate=" ...")
```

end in my template i want to check like:

```
 {% if model.read_more_needed %} <i class='fa fa-info'></i> {% endif %}
```

But Truncate does not returns false even it does not truncate the sentence... How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the result of truncation with the original text:

```
return self.description != Truncator(self.description).words(5, html=True,
                                                             truncate=" ...")
```